# style="top:-90px;" doing nothing

Tags: html, css

I'm currently learning html and CSS. I'm practicing by making a very basic website but have came across an issue when I added another image on top of my background image (the twitter logo). I tried to move the image using `style="top:-90px;"`but there was no effect. What ever classes I used to try to move the image nothing happened. I don't know how to target the image via CSS either.

Please help, sorry I know very little because I'm trying to learn.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style>
    body {
        text-align: center;
        background: url("LINK");
        background-size: cover;
        color: white;
        font-family: sans-serif;
        background-repeat: no-repeat;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        font-weight: lighter;
    }

    p {
        text-align: center;
        font-size: 24px;
        font-family: sans-serif;
    }



</style>
</head>





<body>
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.scottish.parliament.uk/images/Logos%20and%20graphics/TwitterLogoSmall20120927.gif" height="50" width="50" style="top:-90px;"></a>

<p>Hello!</p>
</body>
```

Comment: to make 'top' take effect you need to set the element's display to absolute or relative

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top` doesn't do anything to elements with `position:static` (the default). You should set `position` to:

- `position:relative` Moves the image 90 pixels up
- `position:absolute` Moves the image so its top edge is 90 pixesl above the top edge of its offset container (`<body>` in this case)
- `position:fixed` Moves the image to be 90 pixels above the top of the vieport.

In your situation, I'm fairly sure you want `position:relative`

Comment: Thank you. How would I target just this image in `<style>` instead of the html part?

Answer (score 0):

`top` works with `position: absolute`.

Maybe you wanted to set

```
margin-top: value;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are new to html and css then I recommend put your image and link

`<a href="xyz"><img src="xyz"/></a>`

inside of a div (if you aren't using html5), like this

`<div id="myImage">`
    `<a href="xyz"><img src="xyz"/></a>`
`</div>`

then in your css use
`#myImage {`
`position:relative;`
`top:-90px`

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href="http://www.google.com"><img src="http://www.scottish.parliament.uk/images/Logos%20and%20graphics/TwitterLogoSmall20120927.gif" height="50" width="50" style="top:-90px; position:relative;"></a>
```

Copy this and paste it on your file.

Answer (score -1):

In style you can do:

```
#image{     
    margin-top:90px
}
```

in html

```
<div id="image"><img src...........>
```

This is an example but it will work

Comment: I don't want to target all images just one at a time. How could I do that?